# Double brackets (i.e., {{}}, curly-curly) do not work within tidyr::complete() and tidyr::nesting()

Tags: r, tidyr

I cannot get double brackets (i.e., `{{}}`, curly-curly) to work within `tidyr::complete()` and `tidyr::nesting()` when used in my own function.  This code works:

```
library(tidyverse)

cw_subset <- ChickWeight[, c("Chick", "Time", "weight")]

cw_complete <- cw_subset %>% 
  complete(Time = seq(min(Time), max(Time), by = 1), 
           nesting(Chick))
```

However, if I try to create a function to do the same thing:

```
complete_data <- function(x, variable){
  x %>% 
    complete(Time = seq(min(Time), max(Time), by = 1), 
             nesting({{variable}}))
}

cw_complete <- cw_subset %>% 
  complete_data(variable = Chick)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in eval_tidy(dots[[i]], data = out) : object 'variable' not found
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `complete` as -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

complete_data <- function(x, variable){
  x %>%  complete(Time = seq(min(Time), max(Time), by = 1), {{variable}})
}

cw_complete  <- cw_subset %>%  complete_data(variable = Chick)
```

To use `nesting` you may use `ensym` -

```
complete_data <- function(x, variable){
  x %>% 
    complete(Time = seq(min(Time), max(Time), by = 1), 
             nesting(!!ensym(variable)))
}
```